# Why are some menus created for authenticated users not displaying?

Tags: routes, navigation

Whatever menus created for authenticated user, some menus are displaying and some created menus are not displaying.

If I login as admin, it shows all created menus and its child menus.

Why is this?

Comment: Please check permissions, it sounds to be a permission issue

Comment: @Drupaler: in permission which one i need to select, because from long ago i am trying and even i set "Administer menus and menu items" for authenticated people still not visible... note: the link like rules, admin->configuration->settings  links used in menus are only not appearing, apart from that the menus to create content and views menus are visible why is it?

Comment: how do are you displaying menus? Block or render?

Comment: @Benone: i am creating main menu....no block or render

Comment: Yes but if displaying with block, you can set visibility for user roles.

Comment: i have just created main menu where in it was displaying in the home page few menus link  like admin links rules,configuration for which i used i not displaying

Answer (score 1):

Some of the links are not visible to authenticated user, because the **URL** you provided to respective menu links are not accessible to authenticated user.

**Example**: Suppose menu link is **Add Article** and URL is **/node/add/article**. So here if authenticated user not having Article node add permission, then in such case **Add Article** will not be visible to that user.

Comment: what exactly do i need to do?

Comment: Give authenticated user permission to view these URL's.

Comment: i had enabled this  permission-> authenticated Access administration men
[Display the administration menu at the top of each page.]now admin menu its self not visible

Comment: You are going on wrong direction. Please update the question with menu link and URL which are not visible to Auth users.

Comment: i understand but my concern is after enabling the authenticated Access administration men in permission i am not able to acess my site itself it showing it as ananymous

Comment: I think you have created another issue for this, right? have you given Administer menus and menu items permission to auth user, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31001/discussion-between-kashish-and-nikhil-banait).

Comment: Sorry, I am busy. please go through this http://cheekymonkeymedia.ca/blog/tips-tricks-tools/avoiding-common-mistakes-admin-menu

Comment: i fixed the problem now tell me how to enable the all menus link i  mean where to set the authenticated user permission to view urls